# XGBoost failing after using windowing functions on label column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, xgboost, windowing

I have successfully trained an XGBoost model where `trainDF` is a dataframe hacing two columns: `features` and `label` where we have 11k 1s and 57M 0's (unbalanced dataset). Everything works fine.

```
val udnersample = 0.1
// Undersampling of 0's -- choosing 10%
val training1 = output1.filter($"datestr" < end_period1 && 
    $"label" === 1)
val training0 = output1.filter($"datestr" < end_period1 && 
    $"label" === 0).sample(
    false, undersample)
val training = training0.unionAll(training1)
val traindDF = training.select("label", 
    "features").toDF("label", "features")}
val paramMap = List("eta" -> 0.05,
                    "max_depth" -> 6,
                    "objective" -> "binary:logistic").toMap
val num_trees = 400
val num_cores = 200
val XGBModel = XGBoost.trainWithDataFrame(trainDF, 
                                          paramMap, 
                                          num_trees, 
                                          num_cores, 
                                          useExternalMemory = true)
```

Then, I want to change the y label with some windowing, so that in each group, I can predict y label earlier.

```
val sum_label = "sum_label"
val label_window_length = 19
val sliding_window_label =  Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(
    asc("timestamp")).rowsBetween(0, label_window_length)

val training_source = output1.filter($"datestr" < 
    end_period1).withColumn(
    sum_label, sum($"label").over(sliding_window_label)).drop(
    "label").withColumnRenamed(sum_label, "label")
val training1 = training_source.filter(col("label") === 1)
val training0 = training_source.filter(col("label") === 0).sample(false, 0.099685)
val training = training0.unionAll(training1)
val traindDF = training.select("label", 
    "features").toDF("label", "features")}
```

The result has 57M 0's and 214k 1's (soughly the same number of rows though). No `NA`s in `"label"` column of `trainDF` and the type is still `double (nullable=true)`. Then xgboost fails:

```
Name: ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.java.XGBoostError
Message: XGBoostModel training failed
StackTrace:   at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoost$.postTrackerReturnProcessing(XGBoost.scala:316)
at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoost$.trainWithRDD(XGBoost.scala:293)
at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoostEstimator.train(XGBoostEstimator.scala:138)
at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoostEstimator.train(XGBoostEstimator.scala:35)
at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:118)
at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoost$.trainWithDataFrame(XGBoost.scala:169)
```

I can include the logs as needed. My confusion is that using the windowing function and literally not changing any other setting, causes XGB to fail. I would appreciate any thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that saving the table `traindDF` in hive and reloading it into Spark solves the problem:

```
traindDF.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("database.tablename")
```

Then, you can easily load the table:

```
val traindDF = spark.sql("""select * from database.tablename""")
```

This trick solved the problem. It seems like spark windowing function is a bit unstable and saving the result into a hive table makes it work.

A better way to do this is using windowing functions in hive instead of Spark.